# SQL Data Lineage Viewer

Tags: sql, data-visualization, data-lineage

I was wondering if anyone has seen an open source tool that does something like this:

https://gudusoft.com/sqlflow/#/

I am looking for something that does field level lineage, tried looking around google and I didn't see anything.

Comment: I am building a Lineage tool in open source exactly because I did not find a simple open source app. You can check it out at https://github.com/tokern/lineage . It is very much in alpha stage and there is still a lot of work to be done. Can I ask you a few questions offline ?